# Cant install apps

Tags: insufficient-memory, stock-android, google-apps

I have free memory of about 24 mb left . When i install apps as small as 1 MB it says  insufficient memory. I tried many times but the problem persists. I have rooted my mobile too.

Comment: Read the questions under `insufficient-memory` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings>Apps>All and uninstall Google Play Store. This will uninstall only updates of new version, and replace it with the old version. Then you can download without the "Insufficient Storage ERROR".